# UIBlurEffect not working when trying to take screenshot programically in swift

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext, uiblureffect

I've blurred my view programmatically and added a share extension with screenshot but the screenshot doesn't blur my view in the image. All programming in swift

***Code for blurring***

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style:.Dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = imageView2.frame
self.view.addSubview(blurView)
```

***Code for screenshot***

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try taking the screenshot this way:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Though could you help me, the status bar is missing

Comment: Change `view.drawViewHierarchy...` to `view.window?.drawViewHierarchy...`

Comment: I don't know why you view would not have a window. Try using this: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window`.

Comment: This works perfectly for small views. For big views the screenshot just becomes a white image. Do you know why is this happening and solution for that ?

Comment: This method is a bit slow. Use it wisely. When you don't need to capture the UIVisualEffectView, always use `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)`

Answer (score 6):

I just found Apple has actually documented on how to take a snapshot of UIVisualEffectView:

Capturing a Snapshot of a UIVisualEffectView
Many effects require support from the window that hosts the UIVisualEffectView. Attempting to take a snapshot of only the UIVisualEffectView will result in a snapshot that does not contain the effect. **To take a snapshot of a view hierarchy that contains a UIVisualEffectView, you must take a snapshot of the entire UIWindow or UIScreen that contains it.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C**

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.window.bounds.size);
}
[self.view.window drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```